# With 2.4 ES head plugin not able to connect to external ES server

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, elasticsearch-head

Getting error of 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enable cors in your `elasticsearch.yml` configuration:

```
http.cors.enabled: true
```

Also you need to allow some origin because none is allowed by default:

```
http.cors.allow-origin: "*"
```

Note that allowing all origins (i.e. `"*"`)  is a security risk, so you can also be more restrictive on that

```
http.cors.allow-origin: /https?:\/\/localhost(:[0-9]+)?/
```

Comment: I have not made any such config changes in my stage environment but still able to access, but not for prod. The only difference is ES 2.1 on stage and ES 2.4 on prod and i don't see any such breaking changes in new versions.

Comment: Yes, that was due to a [change](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/breaking-changes-2.3.html#_cors_support_broken_in_2_3_0_and_2_3_1) they made in ES 2.3.